# WordPress cache break a plugin

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache

I've installed  a wp rocket cache plugin on my WordPress it causes many problems with other plugins 
I've deactivated all options on Wp a wp rocket cache plugin and delete it, but other plugins didn't work well.  I need to remove any effects for the wp-rocket cache. Please, can you help me?

Comment: It is better to do a specific question that can derive in a "correct" answer. Asking for generic help is not the best way. As advice, change the title of the question to be a question. Welcome to StackOverflow!!!

Comment: Breeze is a cache plugin that offers the most complete set of functionality for all your WordPress cache management requirements. At the time of this email, it has 20,000+ active installs and the number is rising rapidly. It provides all industry-standard functionalities, completely FOR FREE.https://wordpress.org/plugins/breeze/